# Apparently, ru.SO is launched; time to update the proposal page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, russian-stackoverflow

http://ru.stackoverflow.com is now live; time to update its [proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian)? That's pretty interesting it is possible to commit to the site when it is in the beta phase already :D

Comment: It looks like it's just in the "sandbox phase" right now (not actually live), though [HashCode did already announce it](http://meta.hashcode.ru/research/3747/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's one of the many things we need to button up. The site *is* live, but we're still actively doing *a lot of stuff* behind the scenes to make sure things go smoothly for folks coming back over from HashCode, and there's still some staging things to wratchet down.

It'll probably be some point tomorrow before everything is all neatly buttoned up, but we will update the proposal to look like any other where the site went public.

Comment: Can I report bugs relating to it there?

Comment: So won't it be better to remove it from sites list for now as well?

Comment: (also, it's 2014 years old according to [this](http://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest))

Comment: @ShadowWizard We don't yet have the ability to do it as 'atomically' as we'd like. It's just going to look a little weird in various places for the next 24 or so hours.

Comment: [tag:feature-request]: add "Make This Site Secret" button for devs and CM's. :-D

Comment: @nicael We'll be pleased to see your reports on [Stack Overflow in Russian Meta](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky but won't they be closed if posted in English? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard For sure will be.

Comment: @nicael Sure, if you want to test (as you are excruciatingly good at doing) you can report them on the Russian meta site.

Comment: @Tim I mean on MSE.

Comment: @nicael Sure, if you're more comfortable posting them here, though I will probably migrate / delete them once they're done (since it really is focused on a single site). There's a chance that things you find probably affect the other international sites as well, and you're giving us free testing, so sure - drop 'em here.

Comment: @Tim you'll have to be faster than some users on MSE who might dv/close/delete such questions as off topic. (not me though :))

Comment: I just thought it would be the same policy as with reporting bugs pertaining to pt.SO there.

Comment: @nicael I manage the Internationalization project, and I'm telling you it's fine to post bugs you find on the international sites here, since the meta sites are in different languages. Link to this comment if you need to and e-mail me directly if you need something reopened.

Comment: @nicael [Or just point to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252391/i-found-a-bug-on-a-non-english-site-i-dont-speak-the-language-can-i-post-it-h) (and anyone else that found a bug but wants an English interface to report it)

Comment: Yeh, that's great :)