# I found a bug on a non-English site and I don't speak the language. Can I post it here?

Tags: support, meta, faq-proposed, internationalization, bug-reports

While looking at a few of the new International sites, I got curious and started poking around. I found what appears to be a bug, and something that wasn't translated.

I don't speak the language and I'm not really comfortable posting on the per-site meta as usual. Can I just report this stuff here?

Comment: Interesting question is, how should such a bug be tagged? [tag:specific-site] will be appropriate for example? (then easier to find and move/remove when all is done)

Comment: @Sha I guess with a [site-name-here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portuguese-stackoverflow) :)

Comment: @nicael yeah, but it takes lots of rep to create new tags.

Comment: Then privileged users can tag such questions properly... And anyway, do you see a new localized site launched every day? :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard you can just use the internationalization tag.

Comment: Just in case: it is absolutely fine to report bugs in English on the Meta of StackOverflow in Russian. We had such reports and we're glad to receive more.

Answer (score 17):

#### Is it a 'bug', as in the software working in a way you didn't expect?

Yes, feel free to post it here. On the international sites, it's not just the *content* that is in another language, it's also the entire UI. Translation tools like Google Translate *do* help, but it also breaks things, which might result in certain buttons not working. Still, we want these reports, and want people very familiar with how our software is *supposed* to work letting us know if they find something odd.

Please try whatever you were doing *without* automatic browser translation prior to reporting. The translation process itself can break things in odd ways.

Just keep in mind that these reports *are* very specific to certain sites, and might not stay around for long after being fixed.

Add the [internationalization](/questions/tagged/internationalization) tag to your report, we'll see it.

#### Is it a translation issue?

If you've spotted a missing or *incorrect* translation it's probably best to simply report it  on the appropriate per-site meta, if you're comfortable enough to navigate around enough to post. Remember, automatic in-browser translation can subtly break things, so we recommend turning that off if you intend to actually post something on the site.

If that's simply not working for you, you're welcome to post it here. If you found multiple translation issues, ***please just consolidate them into a single report***. It's also very helpful to take a screen shot of the problematic text so we can immediately see it in context, and this usually obviates the need to translate the report itself.

#### Is MSE really the best place for this?

99% of all bugs get reported directly to the per-site meta sites. However, we currently lack a proper bug reporting mechanism within the translation interface *itself* (working on that), and we want people that find bugs or potentially embarrassing translation issues to be able to let us know - even if they can't navigate around an interface that isn't at all in English.

Meta, for now, while not *ideal* is the best place for these exceptional cases to land in order for the International team to sort them and get them off to a more appropriate place.

Comment: Only bugs though? Feature requests (e.g. change something in the design) are not included?

Comment: @ShadowWizard You really need to be _using_ the site in order to ask for features to be added to it :)

Comment: Like your edit - only thing missing is 'directed at nicael' :P