# Portuguese Stack Overflow help page had mixed English and Portuguese

Tags: bug, status-norepro, help, internationalization, portuguese-stackoverflow

I went to the [Portuguese Stack Overflow help page](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help), and saw this:

> [image]

There are various pieces of English that should be translated into Portuguese.

I don't speak Portuguese, so I don't know what it should be changed to.

Comment: Let's generalize this to: lots and lots of pages on ru.so have a mix of Russian and English. It's obvious to those using the site.

Comment: @pizza Yes? So what? I'm just pointing this out.

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq Yeah, there are still a bunch of strings we know we need to translate. It's an ongoing process. We appreciate the bug report, but I have to ask... why are the screenshots from pt.SO? :)

Comment: Hey! That's Portuguese, not Russian.

Comment: Use Google Translator!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now that I looked at it... The Help Center on Stack Overflow in Russian actually looks pretty English-free to me:

[image: Actually...]

The site translation definitely isn't complete. All of our sites are constantly growing and we are changing copy all over the place. We're working on a better localization workflow, and the ru.SO's community is heavily involved in pointing out and fixing the missing bits for their site.

Give this some time (say, [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/155160) :)), and if there are still things we all have collectively missed, let us know!

Comment: Actually it's Tim's fault, he [encouraged users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252392/152859) to report any bugs right away. :-)

Comment: As you said, that's definitely pt.SO, so maybe edit the question to reflect that fact?

Comment: I edited the question so as it makes sense now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In general, sure. I'm talking about SO in Russian specifically - its translation is new and being more actively worked on than the other two sites' that have been around longer. Let me put it this way: right now translation reports for it are less "oh wow, how did we miss that" and more "yeah, yeah, we know". :)

Comment: He, umm, apparently meant Portuguese. :/

Comment: @TimPost Not sure - it's nicael's edit that brought the question in line with the screenshot.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I didn't encourage users to report bugs right away. I just told users that if they _found_ some, and weren't comfortable posting on the per-site metas for a variety of reasons, here was okay too. I did this after getting a few reports via email from people stating that they didn't feel comfortable, and some earlier reports for Portuguese that folks posted here that were met with a bit of resistance. This made me question if we were not getting some valuable reports simply because of language differences, but it wasn't _meant_ to be a call to action.

Answer (score 5):

The help center articles are not *currently* in Transifex, the tool that we use for collaborative translation. Hence, they're slower to be translated. We *will* be getting these strings in the right places, but translation efforts *on* the help center have already begun using other tools, so at this point letting them finish is the least disruptive thing to do as far as actual progress goes.

Portuguese is also a bit different because it was the first site. Notice, Russian and Japanese have fewer entries, and Japanese has the summary paragraphs ahead of the links. The help center meets the same goal everywhere, but does it a *tad* bit differently.

Anyway, Portuguese will finish the relevant articles, probably add a few of its own, and emerge with much *less* English in the coming months.

Comment: Could you please give more details on the "Russian and Japanese have fewer entries"? On Ru.SO we have a problem with some strings (not from Help Center) absent from Transifex, and, thus, unable to translate. I consider posting it on Meta.SE, but would like to get more information first.