# The words "sign up or login to customize your list" should be localized in Japanese Stack Overflow's main menu

Tags: bug, top-bar, localization

I'm raising this here rather than the site meta per [this question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252391/i-found-a-bug-on-a-non-english-site-and-i-dont-speak-the-language-can-i-post-i)

Go to [Japanese Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) and open the main topbar menu. The words "sign up or login to customize your list" are still in English.

[image: Japanese Stack Overflow]

compare this to the Portuguese version where it is localised.

[image: Portuguese Stack Overflow]

Comment: The translation most like has not come in/been approved yet.